# Rails link_to: Do something after confirmation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, link-to

I'm trying to execute a save action via AJAX using `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to 'Save', image_path(image), method: :patch, 
        data:{ confirm: 'Save image?', remote: true } %>
```

I want the link to be replaced with `<span>Saving...</span>` on confirmation, but can't figure out a clean way to do it.

Problems with existing solutions:

**disable_with:**
If I add `:disable_with => '<span>Saving...</span>'` the inner HTML of the link will be replaced instead of the link itself. Don't want that.

**onclick:**
If I add `:onclick => "$(this).replaceWith('<span>Saving...</span>');"` the link will be replaced immediately, even if the user cancels the confirmation

Is there a solution that fits with Rails 3 UJS best practices?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the hook `ajax:beforeSend` :

```
$('a#my_link_to').bind('ajax:beforeSend', function(evt, xhr, settings) {
  $(this).replaceWith('<span>Saving...</span>');
})
```

And then you could add a bind to `ajax:success` :

```
$('a#my_link_to')
  .bind('ajax:beforeSend', function(evt, xhr, settings) {
    $(this).replaceWith('<span id="saving">Saving...</span>');
  })
  .bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
    $('span#saving').replaceWith('Saved!');
  })
```

Note: Please refer the comment below which also is very important

Comment: Note that the success handler never gets called- because you've replaced `$(this)` the binding gets destroyed...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a case where the functionality you want goes beyond what's offered by Rails' JS helpers. At this point I would just avoid using the :confirm and :remote options to link_to, and implement it in plain jQuery UJS or similar.

You might also think in terms of hiding the link and showing the 'Saving...' span when the user confirms, rather than replacing html; I think it will end up simpler that way, and still give you the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use *confirm:complete* event. (details: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js)

Comment: @hedgesky- This won't work- the `confirm:complete` event fires whether the confirmation was canceled or OK'd.

Comment: You are right, in the doc they say: "The `confirm:complete` event is fired whether or not the user answered true or false to the dialog"

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
<%= link_to 'Save', image_path(image), method: :patch, 
        data:{ confirm: 'Save image?', remote: true }, 
        onclick: "$(this).one('ajax:beforeSend', 
            function(e) { $(this).replaceWith('<span>Saving...</span>'); });" %>
```

(The problem with this solution is that the handlers accumulate if the user clicks, does not confirm, clicks again, etc... Therefore it's not ideal...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `confirm:complete` event. It gets a second boolean argument passed which tells if the result was cancel or ok.